# Selenium get error message on required field

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I use Selenium for a customer end actually i have a problem testing the error message on required field. I explain :

I work on a form with multiples input with the attributes required :

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5Ndv.jpg)

The problem is : No html is generated with the error message. How did you get the actual text error ?

```
<select name="id_role" id="id_role" required="required" data-toggle="values" data-label-options="{&quot;Gestionnaire&quot;:[&quot;affiliation&quot;],&quot;Administrateur&quot;:[&quot;affiliation&quot;],&quot;Manageur&quot;:[&quot;affiliation&quot;],&quot;Utilisateur&quot;:[&quot;affiliation&quot;]}"
```

class="form-control">
    
-- Choix --
    
    Utilisateur
    Gestionnaire
    Manageur Entreprise
    Manageur Client

And second question, is that normal that the error is different in function of the browser ?

Thank you.

Comment: scroll to the top or bottom of your HTML code, you may be able to find web element for this error message. or look for javascript that generates it.

Comment: This message is generated by the browser. Is not part of the dom, so this message isn't in the html code